# Unable to install ApiGen using CLI

Tags: windows, netbeans, apigen

I am trying to install [Apigen](http://www.apigen.org/) on windows.
I am following instructions mentioned [here.](http://anjanasilva.com/blog/how-to-install-apigen-in-netbeans-8-0-using-pear/)

But I am getting following error in cmd: 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ApiGen PEAR is no more supported.
Download PHAR from [apigen.org](http://apigen.org) or install via `composer require apigen/apigen`.